# Store files in Windows Azure Storage using Rails (waz-storage gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have planned to use Windows Azure Storage to save blob data from my Rails application.
I searched the web to find a suitable solution, and found a gem called `waz-storage`.

`conn = WAZ::Storage::Base.establish_connection(:account_name => account_name, :access_key => access_key)`

i tried to use the above block to make a connection, this part is executed successfully. But when i use commands like below

`WAZ::Blobs::Container.find('test-container')`

it fails and shows `403 Forbidden`, i am actually using the account name and access key obtained from my Windows Azure Storage account.

What am i doing wrong in this? or if there is any better solution for storing blob in azure, please suggest.

Comment: same issue here. when I executed `WAZ::Blobs::Container.create('test-container')` it actually created the Container in Azure but when trying to add a blob I keep getting the same error. Have yet to find a solution...

Comment: Try uploading from a real server, not from your localhost. It wont work from localhost it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in the waz-storage gem [issues list](https://github.com/johnnyhalife/waz-storage/issues/32).

First, 'find' the container you want to use (or create one if you'd prefer):

```
container = WAZ::Blobs::Container.find('name_of_container')
```

Then, try this:

```
open('/absolute_path_to_the_file_you_are_uploading', 'rb') do |f|
  container.store('name_of_blob', f.read, 'file_type/extension')
end
```

This worked perfectly for me. Good luck!

Comment: I am trying to do the same you have done in local by using code `conn = WAZ::Storage::Base.establish_connection!( { :account_name => account_name, :access_key => access_key} )
    
    container = WAZ::Blobs::Container.find('test')` but it shows 403 forbidden.. do i have to enable any settings in Azure portal?

Comment: Yes. In the Azure Management Portal click on Storage and then click on Containers. This will list all your containers. Find the one you want to upload to and click on its URL or the Last Modified (just highlight the container but don't click the name). Once highlighted, click on Edit Container in the bottom nav and then change the Access to "Public Container." That did the trick for me.